# RegExp constructor adding unexpected comma to pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

`trigoOperators` is an array containing some trigonometric operations.

The goal is to create a regular expression that parses a string equation into an array.

The problem is that the resulting regular expression is adding an unexpected comma to the pattern as shown in the example below

```js
const trigoOperators = ['abs', 'sqrt']

const rexExp = new RegExp('\\W|(-?\\d+)' + `${(trigoOperators.map(o => `|(${o})`))}`, 'g')

console.log(rexExp)
```

**The expected result is `/\W|(-?\d+)|(abs)|(sqrt)/g` while the current result is `/\W|(-?\d+)|(abs),|(sqrt)/g` (notice the added comma)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.map()` method returns an array. When the template expansion expands that, it'll `.join()` it into a string. That's where the comma comes from. You can override the default `.join()` string:

```js
const trigoOperators = ['abs', 'sqrt']

const rexExp = new RegExp('\\W|(-?\\d+)' + `${(trigoOperators.map(o => `|(${o})`)).join('')}`, 'g')

console.log(rexExp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma appears because the array was coerced to a string.

You can use

```js
const trigoOperators = ['abs', 'sqrt']
const rexExp = new RegExp(String.raw`\W|(-?\d+)${trigoOperators.map(o=>`|(${o})`).join('')}`, 'g')
console.log(rexExp) // => /\W|(-?\d+)|(abs)|(sqrt)/g
```

*Details*:

- `String.raw...` - definition of a raw string literal where a backslash is treated as a literal
- `` ${trigoOperators.map(o=>`|(${o})`).join('')} `` - takes each item inside `trigoOperators` array, wraps them with `|(` and `)` chars, and then *concatenates* the items (using `.join('')`).